# Convert one equation into another form using Maple and see the steps

Tags: maple

I want to convert this equation exp(x - y)/(1 + exp(1)^(x - y))^2 into exp(1)^(x + y)/(exp(1)^x + exp(1)^y)^2 equation. And I want to see the steps to do that in maple.
So far, I checked if both statements are equal using and it gave me a TRUE:

eq1 := exp(x - y)/(1 + exp(1)^(x - y))^2 = exp(1)^(x + y)/(exp(1)^x + exp(1)^y)^2;

is(eq1);

Comment: Your question is not clear........... -1

Answer (score 1):

```
ee := exp(x - y)/(1 + exp(1)^(x - y))^2:

simplify(expand(ee));

      exp(x+y)/(exp(y)+exp(x))^2
```

Amongst several other ways,

```
combine(normal(expand(ee)));

      exp(x+y)/(exp(y)+exp(x))^2
```

Or were you looking for a more step-by-step approach, say in which a factor of `exp(y)^2` were *programmatically* determined and used to adjust both numerator and denominator?